# Socket connection stays alive for some time even after closing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcp

Folks,

My environment is Ubuntu 12.04.

Here is a pseudo-code for my TCP server application that is listening for a connection:

```
while(true) {
    int hConn = accept(hMain, NULL, NULL);

    string s = readClient(hConn);
    if (s == "quit") {
        close(hConn);
    }
 }
```

While my server is running, I telnet to localhost at port nnnn:

```
$ telnet localhost nnnn
quit
Connection closed by foreign host.
$
```

When the server receives "quit," it closes the client connection. This causes the telnet client to quit with an appropriate message.

So far so good.

However, when I run netstat, I can still see that the client connection is still alive.

It takes a few seconds for the connection to disappear.

This happens even if I force quit my server app.

If I run my server app once again, I get an error that port "nnnn" is still in use.

I have to wait for a few seconds before I can run my server app  once again.

Is there something that I am missing? Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Note that I am indeed closing socket hMain when quitting the server although this is not shown in the above pseudo-code.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Is the socket in TIME-WAIT state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware of the `TIME_WAIT` state, which provides that TCP connections which have been closed hang around for a couple of minutes for TCP security/integrity reasons.

The problem with restarting your server can be overcome via the `SO_REUSEADDR` option.

Comment: Thanks. SO_REUSEADDR did the trick. I guess I don't need to worry about the connection hanging around even after closing. Peter